# Combine the same values in a list to display as a range

Tags: python

I have a list of distances associated with each compass bearing from 1 to 360 degrees, also stored as a list. I would like to condense the list so as to give ranges of bearings over which the distance is associated, e.g.

From:

```py
bearings = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
distance = [5, 10, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 10, 10, 5]
```

To:

```py
bearings = [1, 2, 3-5, 6-7, 8-9, 10]
distance = [5, 10, 15, 20, 10, 5]
```

Any ideas what sort of approach to take this on with? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure this is how you want to represent "bearings"? It will convert integers into strings.

Comment: How will this be used? storing 'ranges' like this seems very counter productive, unless this is just to be printed as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The raw integers will still be stored and used for data analysis. This is just a separate process to make it easier for an end user to view and interpret the data.

Comment: Does whatever data analysis/reporting tool you are using have a distribution chart? If so, use that instead of manually computing ranges

Comment: I think the confusion people have is that this: `[1, 2, 3-5, 6-7, 8-9, 10]` is not a python statement of ranges. In python that's the same as `[1, 2, -2, -1, -1, 10]`. So the question is: how do you you *really* want to represent this?

Comment: @drum Yes, I think that may be the best approach. I'll try that instead

Comment: @Mark Agreed, I think a step back and rethink is required. Cheers!

Comment: To be clear: the overall goal here is to set up data that lets you take a bearing as input and look up the corresponding distance?

Comment: The user provides a location and my script produces the list of distances at all 360 bearings. I am trying to present these distances to them in as compact a manner as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'clumping' the distance array by repeating values we can recreate the bearings array

There is probably a more python-ic way to do this, but this is somewhere to start!

```
bearings = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
distance = [5, 10, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 10, 10, 5]

clumps = []
current_clump = []

# Clump repeating distances together
last_val = None
for i in range(len(distance)):
    current_val = distance[i]
    
    # if this element (distance) is the same as the last, add it to the current clump
    # otherwise add the current clump to our clumps list and create a new empty one
    if current_val == last_val or last_val is None:
        current_clump.append(current_val)
    else:
        clumps.append(current_clump)
        current_clump = [current_val]

    last_val = current_val

# Add the 'leftover' clump after the loop is done
clumps.append(current_clump)

# Create the output "ranged_indices" array that will have our desired ranged values
ranged_indices = []
current_indice = 0;
for i in range(len(clumps)):
    current_len = len(clumps[i])
    if current_len == 1:
        ranged_indices.append(current_indice+1)
    else:
        high_end = (current_indice+current_len)
        ranged_indices.append(str(current_indice+1)+'-'+str(high_end))

    current_indice += current_len

print(ranged_indices)
print(clumps)
```

Comment: This certainly looks like a good place to start - thanks!

Comment: I managed to manipulate this to provide me with exactly what I wanted - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I tried doing this in one line with `itertools.groupby`.  If you're writing throwaway code for data munging or something, this will do.  Otherwise, I recommend breaking it out into a `for` loop so it's more maintainable.

```
from itertools import groupby

bearings = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
distance = [5, 10, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 10, 10, 5]

new_bearings, new_distance = zip(
    *[
        (f"{pairs[0][0]}-{pairs[-1][0]}", k) 
        if len(pairs) > 1
        else (str(pairs[0][0]), pairs[0][1])
        for k, pairs in [
            (k, list(g))
            for k, g in groupby(zip(bearings, distance), key=lambda x: x[1])
        ]
    ]
)

print(f"{new_bearings=}")
# new_bearings=('1', '2', '3-5', '6-7', '8-9', '10')

print(f"{new_distance=}")
# new_distance=(5, 10, 15, 20, 10, 5)
```

I hate it :-)

The idea is the inner loop is grouping by your distances and giving tuples where they're the same.  You need to return `(k, list(g))` because `g` is an iterator and you need a list for `len` and slicing.

Once you have the lists of tuples, the ugly string operations are to give your `lower-upper` notation, or just converting the first element to a string if there's only a single pair.